# Getting `insufficient funds for gas * price + value` error when performing transaction with another account than Alice

Tags: balances, account, frontier, frontier-node-template

I'd like to use Substrate Frontier as a private blockchain for my current project. I have set up a project using a frontier-template-node build and I am now trying to adjust its settings.

I am currently stuck with issues with accounts I generated:

- In the chain specification file (customSpec.yml), I replaced the sudo account id of Alice by an account id I created. This account is not able to deploy a contract but Alice is still authorized to do it. I get the error `Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value` while the substrate and EVM balances of the account seems well funded.
- All the user accounts I created are not able to perform a transaction. I get the same error `Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value` even with a balance of `1,000,000,000 ETH`

Here is a sample call I execute on my code:

```
    // Load contract
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress, {
      from: signerAddress,
      gasPrice: '0x3B9ACA00',
    });

    // Prepare method transaction
    const encodedMethod = await contract.methods.transfer([userAddress, 100]).encodeABI();

    // Sign transaction
    const methodTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
      {
        from: signerAddress,
        to: contractAddress,
        data: encodedMethod,
        gasPrice: '0x3B9ACA00',
        gas: '0x1000000',
      },
      signerPrivateKey,
    );

    // Send transaction
    const txReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(methodTx.rawTransaction);
```

Could you give me some advices to fix this issue?

Comment: Not super familiar with Frontier, but in your chain spec, when substituting the account for SUDO, have you also include that account in he vec of pre-funded accounts ?
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/blob/1b6bff4e88e6d0345887c0ecbd63401f9474aa91/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L99-L113

Comment: So, for what I can see this error happens either when the gas price is too low, the accounts don't have enough funds, or when there is an [invalid payment input](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/e3ee95ab59d4ce04ec23110abe56ea69af8e79e1/primitives/evm/src/validation.rs#L170)

Comment: @AlejandroMartínez Yes I added this account to the pre-funded accounts list and its balance is very high (0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff). The account has been created with the command line `./target/release/frontier-template-node key generate` with a password and I wonder if it could be the reason to the problem. It looks like the `privateKey` I passed to the transaction is not properly linked to the account. Could it be the problem and i there a way to give the password in order to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you also changed the accounts set for the [EVM compatibilty](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/73e6223e8bc26bf8e57cd9b212f1bc2fd288c5ca/template/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L176-L196) ?

Comment: @AlejandroMartínez I have changed accounts directly in the json generated by the command `./target/release/frontier-template-node build-spec --disable-default-bootnode --chain local > customSpec.json` in both sections `balances` and `evm.accounts`. Should I edit the chain_spec.rs before generating the json?

Comment: That is not necessary if you are specifying that chain spec file you are generating when launching your nodes. I suspect you do.

Comment: @AlejandroMartínez Do you know what is the right way to create a sudo account which can be used with `web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(_privateKey)`? When I use Alice account private key, it returns the right account address, but when I use the private key of an account generated with `./target/release/frontier-template-node key generate` the addresses does not match.

Comment: You can install in your code Web3 or ethers to see the balance, can you have this line const balanceFrom = web3.utils.fromWei(await web3.eth.getBalance(your-address-here), 'ether'); before and after the transaction, to see if is spending gas

Comment: Relevant post https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6674/private-key-for-evm-frontier/6690

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue.

The `Public key (hex)` returned by the substrate command line `./target/release/frontier-template-node key generate --scheme Sr25519` does not worked for the `evm` accounts configuration in `customSpec.yml`.

I generated the right public key by calling the `privateKeyToAccount` function of Web3.js:

```
import Web3Accounts from 'web3-eth-accounts';
const ethPublicKey = new Web3Accounts().privateKeyToAccount(privateKey).address;
```

Then the eth balance is correctly assign to my sudo account at the initialization of my local blockchain and I can use it to make transaction and fund other accounts.