# How substrate / frontier convert address

Tags: evm, frontier, address

We are using frontier with substrate to be able to deploy evm smart contract.
When I create a transfer between two evm address and that the second one does not exist, the node create a new ss58 address, but I can't figure out what is the used algo? because it does not correspond to subkey is giving for example?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculated it with this tool: [Substrate EVM Utilities](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/blob/main/utils/README.md#--evm-address-address).
An example with a random account generated:

```
  Secret phrase:     worth wrestle meat ecology merry ginger online glad soda usage peasant lava
  Network ID:        substrate
  Secret seed:       0x8e940c2a136dadf87c3b4b408866ff5fb1cbb64893a933493341c5e400a81690
  Public key (hex):  0x381faf1906bf0ea763e7e25f110b26b880680d55bed21f52b76d9d5973fcee6e
  Account ID:        0x381faf1906bf0ea763e7e25f110b26b880680d55bed21f52b76d9d5973fcee6e
  Public key (SS58): 5DLHx6nDCn9EiYHryuyELhvsDKBmZGwLZthSdD3cshjAzusN
  SS58 Address:      5DLHx6nDCn9EiYHryuyELhvsDKBmZGwLZthSdD3cshjAzusN
```

I calculated the Ethereum Address for my account, basically truncating the Public key (hex) value above: `0x381faf1906bf0ea763e7e25f110b26b880680d55`

See the Susbtrate docs [Access EVM accounts](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts/), for more info. And I open a question here a long time with a doubt with the private keys on Frontier if you want more information on that too: [Private key for EVM Frontier](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6674/private-key-for-evm-frontier)