# How to interact with EVM contracts using polkadotJS

Tags: polkadot-js, evm

Is there a tutorial explaining how to interact with EVM smart contracts using PolkadotJS?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Substrate tutorial: [Access EVM accounts](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts)

You can go to the point where it [checks the account storage](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts/#view-account-storage), to see how is doing it using polkadotJS UI: query the state `accountStorages` from evm pallet, specifying the smart contract address and the storage slot for the address (How to calculate the storage slot here: [Substrate EVM Utilities)](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/blob/main/utils/README.md#--erc20-slot-slot-address).

An JS example of that:

```js
const balance = api.query.evm.accountStorages(smartContractAddress, storageSlot);
```

If you have a doubt about how to manage the keys, I opened a StackExchange question a while ago: [Private key for EVM Frontier](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6674/private-key-for-evm-frontier?noredirect=1&lq=1) that has amazing explanation about it.